# Swap data of /dev/sda2 and /dev/sda3

Tags: linux, filesystems

To begin with ,I would build up the exact context to begin with. The link(cuz am low on reputations) is a screenshot of partitions in my laptop's hard disk.[Hard disk filesystem partitions **/dev/sda**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQnsD.png)

As it must have been evident from the screenshot itself..**/dev/sda2** was a pre-existing partitions which has now been formatted into a clean **btrfs** format; And **/dev/sda3** has *ParrotOS* in it.
Now I wish to make whole of hard disk memory from **/dev/sda2** and **/dev/sda3** to *ParrotOS* without losing any iota of any existing data in **/dev/sda3**...as per the software used here(*Gparted*) partitions can be extended only if they have empty unallocated space after them, so there is no apparent option here for to directly unallocate **/dev/sda2** and put **/dev/sda3** in front of it..Or is it?

Can some generous guys help me to atleast aid me to swap everything from **/dev/sda3** so that I can unallocate it and can merge them together into a single large chunk of partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `sda2` and `sda3` are the same size (low-level size, that is... not FS size... you can see that with say fdisk), then you can copy **binary** content of `sda3` into `sda2` with something as simple as:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda3 of=/dev/sda2
```

After that is done, `sda2` would be an exact image of `sda3`. Just make sure to not have the partition of `sda3` (or sda2, of course) mounted so that there are no operations going on against it. When that is copied over, you should be able to mount `sda2` and see what you have in `sda3`.... when that is done, you can then remove `sda3` so that `sda2` can be extended.... this is not risk free, by the way... and some adjustments will need to be made, for example, adjusting `/etc/fstab` (among other things).

Comment: can you please elaborate more into "some adjustments will need to be made, for example, adjusting /etc/fstab (among other things)"???

Comment: I don't know what they might be but if you have the `sda3` partition set to be mounted in `/etc/fstab`... well, that will have to be adjusted.